# How do I configure Log4j to read my properties file?

Tags: java, log4j, smslib

I am sending an SMS using `SMSLib` in Java.  I have loaded the log4j jar file and placed the `log4j.properties` file in the right place, but it still can't read it and gets the below exception:

Exception text:

> log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file [log4j.properties].
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException: log4j.properties (Le fichier spécifié est introuvable)
>           at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
>           at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)
>           at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:97)
>           at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:372)
>           at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:403)
>           at org.smslib.helper.Logger.(Logger.java:50)
>           at org.smslib.helper.Logger.(Logger.java:29)
>           at org.smslib.Service.listSystemInformation(Service.java:113)
>           at org.smslib.Service.initializeService(Service.java:103)
>           at org.smslib.Service.(Service.java:95)
>           at org.smslib.Service.(Service.java:90)
>           at laposte.EnvoiSMS.(EnvoiSMS.java:181)
>           at laposte.login.passwordKeyPressed(login.java:230)
>           at laposte.login.access$100(login.java:26)
>           at laposte.login$2.keyPressed(login.java:80)
>           at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6463)
>           at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2829)
>           at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6282)
>           at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
>           at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
>           at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
>           at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
>           at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1895)
>           at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:762)
>           at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1027)
>           at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:899)
>           at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:727)
>           at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4731)
>           at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
>           at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
>           at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>           at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
>       log4j:ERROR Ignoring configuration file [log4j.properties].
>       log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (smslib).
>       log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
>       log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

Comment: You probably didn't place it in the right place :). Where did you put it. You sure it's on the classpath?

Comment: Please provide the location of your application and properties file in relation to each other.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to place the file on the classpath.Try placing it in a folder that is on the classpath like the source folder.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302531/how-to-place-a-file-on-classpath-in-eclipse) might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

> log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file [log4j.properties]. java.io.FileNotFoundException:

First you should save name as log4j.properties and select as file type as All Files and then click on save, and save location should be your project (note: don't save it in your workspace).

#### Log4j Properties: "log4j.properties"

This is the code for generating logs. Save it as log4j.properties.

```
// Here we have defined root logger
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,CONSOLE,R,HTML,TTCC

// Here we define the appender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.TTCC=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.HTML=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender

// Here we define log file location
log4j.appender.R.File=./log/testlog.log
log4j.appender.TTCC.File=./log/testlog1.log
log4j.appender.HTML.File=./log/application.html

// Here we define the layout and pattern
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern= %5p [%t] (%F:%L)- %m%n
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d - %c -%p - %m%n
log4j.appender.TTCC.layout=org.apache.log4j.TTCCLayout
log4j.appender.TTCC.layout.DateFormat=ISO8601
log4j.appender.HTML.layout=org.apache.log4j.HTMLLayout
log4j.appender.HTML.layout.Title=Application log
log4j.appender.HTML.layout.LocationInfo=true
```

Comment: Please do explain your code rather than just writing down the stuff.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.