# Spring MVC message.properties issue

Tags: spring-mvc

I am not able to read form my messages.properties file (under/src/main/resources)

> Env:  Spring MVC 4.3.14

MyAppConfig.java:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("messages");
    return messageSource;
}
```

In my jsp (newuserregistration.jsp) i have:

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="user" class="form-horizontal">


<div class="row">
<label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="userfirstname">First
    Name</label>
<div class="col-md-7">
    <form:input type="text" path="userfirstname" id="userfirstname"
class="form-control input-sm" />
    <div class="has-error">
        <form:errors path="userfirstname" class="help-inline" />
    </div>
</div>
```

In my css i have:

```
.has-error{
color:red;
```

}

Entity class (AppUsers.java) has:

```
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@NotEmpty
//@Size(min = 1, max = 45)
@Column(name = "USERFIRSTNAME", nullable = false, length = 45)
private String userfirstname;
```

My messages.properties has:

```
NotEmpty.user.userfirstname=First name can not be blank.
```

And controller has:

```
 @Autowired
MessageSource messageSource;

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/registernewuser"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String newUser(ModelMap model) {
    AppUsers user = new AppUsers();
    model.addAttribute("user", user);



 @RequestMapping(value = {"/registernewuser"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveUser(@Valid AppUsers user, BindingResult result,
        ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
if (result.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        return "newuserregistration";
    }
```

Somehow the error message is not displayed on my jsp. What I am missing or doing wrong here?

I did sysout for result and it gave me -

```
org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors  Field error in object 'appUsers' on field 'userfirstname': rejected value []; codes [NotEmpty.appUsers.userfirstname,NotEmpty.userfirstname,NotEmpty.java.lang.String,NotEmpty]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [appUsers.userfirstname,userfirstname]; arguments []; default message [userfirstname]]; default message [may not be empty]
```

Comment: Not sure if it is connected to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533680/spring-mvc-not-able-to-read-messages-properties-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me:

Removed model.addAttribute("user", user); and Added -- @ModelAttribute("user") -- attribute to my POST method. Here is the working snippet:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/registernewuser"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveUser(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid AppUsers user, BindingResult result,
        ModelMap model) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        return "newuserregistration";
    }
```

However I am still wondering what was wrong in the initial situation.

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove NotEmpty.user prefix from resource file.

Resource file **message.properties**

`userfirstname=First name can not be blank.`

Comment: I tried "userfirstname=First name can not be blank" (without quotes). No luck. Still same result.

Comment: Did you tried adding explicit message in @NotEmpty validation i.e.  @NotEmpty(message = "NotEmpty.user.userfirstname")

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but no luck following what you suggested in your last comments.