# How can I load a file relative to a class's package?

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, junit, junit4

I have the file `allDepartments.json` in a subdirectory called `fixtures`, to which I want to access from the `Fixture.java` class.

[image]

This is my Fixture.java code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public final class Fixture {
    private static final String FIXTURES_PATH = "";
    private final String fixture;

    public Fixture(String fixtureName) throws IOException {
        fixture = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(FIXTURES_PATH + fixtureName)));
    }

    public final String getFixture() {
        return fixture;
    }
}
```

However every time he tries to access the file I get a `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: allDepartments.json`...

I have heard of the `getResource()` method and tried every combination possible of it, without success.

I need this to store multi-line strings for my JUnit tests.

What can I do?

Comment: Is this file a resource? Is it packaged into the final JAR?

Comment: No, well, hope not. I want to use this just for the unitary tests (which can be run in Eclipse or during a maven install procedure).

Comment: Ah so you have a Maven project and this file is under `src/test/resources`? (I can't see your screenshot if that's what it is)

Comment: Sort of. I am not using `src/test/resources`, would it solve my issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [NIO.2 API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) can't be used to read files that are effectively project resources, i.e. files present on the classpath.

In your situation, you have a Maven project and a resource that you want to read during the unit test of the application. First, this implies that this resources should be placed under `src/test/resources` so that Maven adds it automatically to the classpath during the tests. Second, this implies that you can't use the `Files` utility to read it.

You will need to resort to using a traditional `BufferedReader`:

```
public Fixture(String fixtureName) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Fixture.class.getResourceAsStream(FIXTURES_PATH + fixtureName)))) {
        // do your thing with br.readLine();
    }
}
```

Note the path given to `getResourceAsStream` is either relative to the current class or absolute. If the resources is located in `src/test/resources/folder/allDepartments.json` then a valid path would be `/folder/allDepartments.json`.

Answer (score 1):

Add `allDepartments.json` to the`.classpath` file  of the project and java should be able to pick it up.

Refer this topic if you want to know [how to add a file to class path from eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302531/how-to-place-a-file-on-classpath-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

when you run Fixtures.java the relative path would be

> ../fixtures/allDepartments.json

try using this path.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for helping and suggestions.

Thanks to you I was able to put things working, so here is the trick (which I guess only works for Maven projects):

I moved the `allDepartments.json` file to the default `src/test/resources` folder as suggested by you guys. I didn't even had to modify the `pom.xml`. And now everything works!

So this is my project structure now:

[image]

And the final Fixture.java code is:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public final class Fixture {
    private final String fixture;

    public Fixture(String fixtureName) throws IOException {
        fixture = this.readFile(fixtureName);
    }

    private String readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        final InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("fixtures/" + fileName).openStream();
        final BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        try {
            return buffer.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
        } finally {
            buffer.close();
        }
    }

    public final String getFixture() {
        return fixture;
    }
}
```