# log4j.properties file not found in project

Tags: java, maven, log4j

I am using Log4j in my project and trying to run my application but it seems it cannot find log4.properties file.

This is my Maven configuration:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>log4j.properties</include>
                <include>hibernate.cfg.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>File-Name</finalName>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>my.main.class</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And this is how I am loading the log4j.properties file in my code.

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
```

When I try to run the application I get the following error:

> log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file [log4j.properties].
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: log4j.properties (No such file or directory)

The weird thing is that if I package my application with **mvn package** and open the jar file I can see the log4j.properties file inside. I don't understand what is wrong since I declare the resources folder in the pom file.

**EDIT:** I am adding the dependency I use for log4j in the project

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

log4j.properties file is inside the src/main/resources folder

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this line was causing the error

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
```

Apparently as long as the `<directory>/src/main/resource</directory>` is set in maven and the file log4j.properties file exists inside the resources folder I can use the Logger directly without this line

Answer (score 0):

If you are using log4j 2.X, the configuration is different.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Please check my edit in the question

Comment: have you tried putting the config file in src/main/resources? Try it without using `PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");` after you place the file in the aforementioned directory

Comment: It's already there. Check the picture I added in my edit

Comment: If that's not the case I'm not really sure what to do. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302531/how-to-place-a-file-on-classpath-in-eclipse) link to see if it helps